# All iOS Device users using the Facebook App's built-in browser are seeing error 404 or page not found

Tags: facebook

Just these past 2 days, all of the iOS users have complained that they are hitting a Page not found from their Facebook APP built-in browser to my site. It's been quite stressful for me.

The URLs have Chinese in them, and have always worked until these couple of days (I suppose when the built-in browsers started to work).

Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue. In our urls we have hashes (#) when **we remove it** from shared links it works normally.

Question is why facebook built-in browser doesn't like hashes?

It can be connected with release new version of facebook app on iOS systems which was pushed on 29th August.